# How to return only Object instead of List of objects?

Tags: hibernate, list

I have a table like Product(id, productName, .... 21 other columns). Using hibernate, the java code is like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Products implements java.io.Serializable {
    int id;
    String productName;
    String productCategory;

    // getter & setter    
}
```

To get the list of items based on [id and productName], the code looks like the following and it's work fine:

```
public List<Products> getProducts(int id, String productName) {

        // session and transaction stuffs

        String queryString = "from Products p WHERE p.id = ? and p.productName = ?";
        Query query = s.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter(0,id);
        query.setParameter(1,productName);
        List list = query.list();

        // comiting and closing

        return list;    
}
```

But if i tried to get the result without List, I am getting error to implement that. Can anybody give me hint what is the way I need to implement. I use casting to implement this but still I am getting error. I tried to implement the following way:

```
public Products getProducts(int id, String productName) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

**Hibernate**: get() method of Session (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Session.html)
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/retrieve-object-by-id-in-hibernate/

**JPA**: find() method of EntityManager (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve

By definition list() API returns query result as List, so you can try to return the first element from the list or get single result and cast it using

**Hibernate**: Query.uniqueResult()
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult()

**JPA**: Query.getSingleResult()
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult()

Comment: Using the following line it can query the result: Products p = (Products) session.get(Products.class, id);[if i search only through id] But here i have to search using (int id, String productName). I am confused how to do this. Because using the output, i have to query again on the same table to get the final output.

Comment: as mentioned by Kaushal, for get single object you can use: query.uniqueResult();